# Hibernate error: executeQuery method cannot be used for update

Tags: java, hibernate, db2

When I run the following:

```
    Session session = null;
    Transaction tx = null;
    List<Intake> intakes = null;
    try{
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        intakes = session.createQuery("from Intake i where i.assignedTo=?")
                .setParameter(0, assignedTo).list();
        tx.commit();
    }
    catch(HibernateException e){
        tx.rollback();
        logger.warn("Unable to list intakes for user " + assignedTo, e);
    }
```

Hibernate always throws an exception and spits the following out to the console:

```
6406 [httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-1] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: -99999, SQLState: null
6406 [httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-1] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - executeQuery method cannot be used for update.
```

Which is caused by:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.SqlException: executeQuery method cannot be used for update.
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.hd.a(hd.java:2508)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.id.d(id.java:1952)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.id.X(id.java:505)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.id.executeQuery(id.java:488)
```

Why is Hibernate giving me an error here when`from Intake i where i.assignedTo=?` is obviously not an update?  I suspect it has something to do with the IBM DB2 JDBC Driver.  I'm using DB2 Driver version 2.7.58.

Here is my Spring Hibernate configuration.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>domain/Intake.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>domain/Action.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
                hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread
                hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
                hibernate.show_sql=true
                hibernate.format_sql=true
                hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
                hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
           </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Try the full version - i.e. `SELECT i FROM Intake i where i.assignedTo=?`;
2. If this doesn't work - upgrade the JDBC driver;
3. If this doesn't work or there is no new version - file a bug for the JDBC driver.

Comment: The full query didn't do anything, but I updated the driver to 3.57.82 and now it works!  I was looking around Google for an answer previously, and found that it was because DB2 did not support the `hibernate.use_sql_comments` setting.  Well, it turns out the latest JDBC driver does in fact support it!